# sp.web.hubSiteData property is not showing up

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I am trying to use pnp.sp.web.hubSiteData on my SPFX code, my problem is that hubSiteData property is not showing or coming up I have installed pnpjs to my solution by running npm install sp-pnp-js --save. is there other library that I need to add or import?

[image]

Comment: you want to get the hubsiteid for the site ? Because `pnp.sp.web.hubsitedata` is a method and not a property

Comment: sorry about that Gautam Sheth, I am new to SPFX.. hehe.. basically I just want to be able to use hubsitedata to get a list of site associated to a hub site. same here https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/webs/#hubsitedata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `web.hubSiteData()` method does not show up is that there is a missing `@pnp/sp/hubsites` import:

```
import { IHubSiteWebData } from "@pnp/sp/hubsites";
```

Once you add this import to the script file, the autocomplete for the `hubSiteData()` should start working.

Comment: Thanks @DenisMolodtsov